# If Else statements inside for loop

Tags: python, selenium

I'm just making a simple script that goes to a webpage of real estate listings clicks on the on the listings, opens the agents website, prints out the URL, and then closes the page and returns back to the listings page to continue on to the next listings. I've hit a wall though, on some of the listings the agents don't have websites so i get an error saying the script can't find the element obviously because it's not there in which case the script stops. How could I use an if-else statement in the for loop that will close the opened listing with no agent website and return back to the listings page to move on to checking the next listing?

Here is the loop:

```
time.sleep(15)
for i in range(1,9):
    listing_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="m_property_lst_cnt_realtor_more_'+str(i)+'"]').click()
    realtor_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lblMediaLinks"]/a').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: len(driver.window_handles) == 2)
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    print(driver.current_url)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.get(home_page)
    time.sleep(10)
```

(P.S, I know sleep() is bad practice. I'm just focusing on basic "how can get the script to work" rather than better way of building. Once that is done I can learn how to make it better)

Comment: I would probably use a try-except here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an if-else, you could use a try-except:

```
    time.sleep(15)
for i in range(1,9):
    listing_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="m_property_lst_cnt_realtor_more_'+str(i)+'"]').click()
    try:
        realtor_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lblMediaLinks"]/a').click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: len(driver.window_handles) == 2)
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    except:
           print("Not found")
           continue
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.get(home_page)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Instead of throwing an error and stopping, it should skip over that part of the code and continue as expected.

Comment: The problem with this is that when except is run it closes the entire session because no agent website was opened. So instead of driver.close() running on that newly opened webpage it just closes everything.

Comment: @Dotpy Try using 'continue' after the except. 'continue' should restart the loop with the next item, instead of breaking out of it. I updated my code, lemme know if it works!

Comment: Okay so that works! BUT, now I have to bring that page back to home_page  but if I insert that above driver.close() it stops the loop LOL now I think this might be out of the scope of this question :P @Brosta

Comment: Oh I think that is because of the way I indented the code after the except block. I just updated my code again, check it out! @Dotpy

Comment: Hmm, still the same issue. I might have to just insert another driver.get(home_page) to open up the original page again then starting over the loop and closing everything else. But this will make it much more of a process. @Brosta

Comment: Well goodluck, hopefully what I posted helped you a little! I have been meaning to learn more about selenium, so if I think of anything during that process I'll come back and post! @Dotpy

Comment: You helped a lot, thank you. I made a new question for this problem cause now it's unrelated to this question since it's been answered! Cheers! @Brosta

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! If it's not too much trouble, an upvote on the answer would be greatly appreciated. Have a great day! @Dotpy

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a try, except around the code that is giving the error. Try this and see if it works:

```
time.sleep(15)
for i in range(1,9):
    listing_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="m_property_lst_cnt_realtor_more_'+str(i)+'"]').click()

    try:
        realtor_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lblMediaLinks"]/a').click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: len(driver.window_handles) == 2)
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        print(driver.current_url)

    except:
        print('No URL Found')
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.get(home_page)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: This does seem to work but when except is executed it closes the entire session instead of continuing on to the next listing. How I can change driver.close() from doing that?